# Need help for creating recursive function without multiple returns

Tags: c, recursion, ansi-c

I'd want to ask a question about the project that I must do for my procedural programming course.
The test wants me to solve this problem:

In advance, I must say that for the "two sets of real number", I used two linked lists, and not arrays.
The problem is that my professor has a list of "not-to-do" things that I must follow, in order to solve the test without penalty, and the real problem is that he doesn't want multiple "returns" inside the body of a function, and I'm not recognizing a way to do those recursive function without multiple escapes, I'd really appreciate a help from someone that could solve this problem.

For the problem, I've created the two sets of real numbers as two linked-lists in the following struct:

```
typedef struct elem_list {
    int info;
    struct elem_list *next;
}   elem_list_t;
```

In the main program the two lists are created by the user from input and they're called list_A and list_B.

Comment: So what is the problem? I don't see any attempt to code those functions?

Comment: Structure each routine as a set of `if`…`else` statements or other code (e.g., loops where suitable) that always calculates a result and stores it in a temporary variable. At the end of the function, return the value of that temporary variable.

Comment: What kind of help do you expect from this site?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to calculate unions and intersections, you'll want the data to be sorted in advance.

Mathematical sets are best implemented as sorted binary trees. From there on, recursion comes fairly natural, since binary tree algorithms are often implemented as recursive. Searching, sorting, balancing etc. So the main part of this assignment should be about implementing an abstract data type for a binary tree.

Regarding multiple returns, it doesn't make sense to dogmatically avoid them, though perhaps the teacher wants to ensure that you are using so-called "tail recursion" with the recursive call at the very end of the function. Because this is typically the only kind of recursion that the compiler can optimize well - all other forms of recursion are terribly slow.